# use one sql connection object in whole program in java

Tags: java, sql, javafx

I want to login with SQL username and password as it is easy to give permission to database. Connection made successfully but I want to use same URL and credentials in whole program, but don't know how to use. I have below code in two different classes

This is my login page which work fine

```
public class login {
    static String connectionUrl;
    @FXML
    private TextField loginusername_txt;
    @FXML
    private TextField loginpassword_txt;
    public final String url() throws SQLException {
        return connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://WIN\\SQLEXPRESS:1433;database=itinventory;" + "user=" + loginusername_txt.getText() + ";" + "password=" + loginpassword_txt.getText() + ";";

    }
    public final Connection conn() throws SQLException {
        Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url());
        return connect;
    }
    public void connection(ActionEvent Event) throws Exception {


        try (Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url());) {
            // Code here.
            Stage main = new Stage();
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/main.fxml"));

            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            main.setScene(scene);
            main.show();

            loginusername_txt.clear();
            loginpassword_txt.clear();

        }
        // Handle any errors that may have occurred.
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

//another class coding is
//full code for controller class is                                                                                                        public class controller {
login log = new login();
Stage main = new Stage();                                                                                                                 @FXML
private MenuItem mainip_menuitem;
public void laptop(ActionEvent Event) throws Exception
{
    AnchorPane root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/laptop.fxml"));
    samewindow(root);
}
@FXML
AnchorPane main_pain;
public void samewindow(AnchorPane samepane)
{
    main_pain.getChildren().setAll(samepane);
}
@FXML
private ComboBox laptopos_combo;
public void filloscombo() throws SQLException
{
    String query="Select * from operatingsystem";
    PreparedStatement pst = log.conn().prepareStatement(query);
            //.prepareStatement(query);
    ResultSet os = pst.executeQuery();
    while(os.next())
    {
        System.out.println(os);
    }
}
```

While run second code it shows this error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException


Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at application.login.url(login.java:24)
    at application.login.conn(login.java:29)
    at application.controller.filloscombo(controller.java:61)
```

Comment: What line is line 24?

Comment: line no 24 is  return connectionUrl ="jdbc:sqlserver://WIN\\SQLEXPRESS:1433;database=itinventory;" + "user="+loginusername_txt.getText() +";"+ "password="+loginpassword_txt.getText()+";";

Comment: There are many options for this with Spring, here are some tutorials https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-data-jpa.

Comment: in string url method

Comment: This looks like a controller class for a FXML file (since you have `@FXML`-annotated fields). The `@FXML`-annotated fields will only be initialized in the controller instance (when the FXML file is loaded). They won't somehow be magically initialized (what would they be initialized to?) in an arbitrary instance of the class you create (with `new login()`). You need to access the *actual controller*. OT: please use proper Java naming conventions. It is extremely difficult to read you code when we can't easily see what is a class name, what is a variable name, etc.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Answer (score -1):

The field `loginusername_txt` and `loginpassword_txt` haven't been initialized and is being accessed by the constructor. You need to initialize it and not just declare it.

Comment: loginusername_txt is a text box to enter the login credentials

Comment: That's fine, but it's likely null. Use a debugging tool to determine if it is or not, or a simple SOUT call before line 24.

Comment: i think after login it clear the content of loginusername_txt as i use loginusername_txt.clear() at last. could you tell me how textbox value permanent save in variable even it clear after login

Comment: However, it's *always* a mistake to initialize fields annotated with `@FXML`, since they are intended to be initialized by the `FXMLLoader`.

Comment: please provide some example from above cod3

Comment: @SukhmanjitSingh How? The code you posted doesn't even load the FXML. Create a [mre] and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62428190/edit) your question to include it. No-one can answer the question correctly from the information you have provided.

Comment: still not find any solution